# Draw the spherical surface of $\rho=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to draw the surface of $\rho=1$.

Is it valid to say that one must draw the spherical surface with $\rho=1$, $\theta = 0$, and $\phi=0$?

This is the resultant graph (plotted with this tool: http://mathinsight.org/spherical_coordinates):

[image: p=1]

Comment: Isn't $\rho=1$, $\theta=0$, $\phi=0$ a point, not a surface?  Are you sure they don't mean three different surfaces?

Answer (score 1):

When asked to plot the graph of $\rho=1$, the implication is that both $\theta$ and $\phi$ are to range through all their values; i.e. $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $0\le \phi \le \pi$. Setting $\theta = \phi =0$ in addition to $\rho=1$ does indeed define a point in 3-space.

Comment: I have this new graph according to your answer, @Ethan Hunt:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4h8oblwa2xn7jw/T1%20-%20p%201%20%5B2%5D.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes, that is correct and what $\rho=1$, a sphere of radius $1$ centered at the origin, looks like.